# AWS ECR get-login-password - Invalid choice on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, aws-cli, amazon-ecr

When trying to run the `get-login-password` command in `aws ecr`, I get a message saying it's an invalid choice:

```
$ aws --region=us-west-1 ecr get-login-password
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
aws: error: argument operation: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

batch-check-layer-availability           | batch-delete-image                      
batch-get-image                          | complete-layer-upload                   
create-repository                        | delete-lifecycle-policy                 
delete-repository                        | delete-repository-policy                
describe-images                          | describe-repositories                   
get-authorization-token                  | get-download-url-for-layer              
get-lifecycle-policy                     | get-lifecycle-policy-preview            
get-repository-policy                    | initiate-layer-upload                   
list-images                              | put-image                               
put-lifecycle-policy                     | set-repository-policy                   
start-lifecycle-policy-preview           | upload-layer-part                       
get-login                                | help
```

Is this a Mac-only tool?  ECR does seem to be installed but the issue is `get-login-password`.  I installed the latest AWS client via these instructions https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/install-cliv2-linux.html

Comment: Did you downloaded the binary or did you use `apt` (`apt-get`) to install it?

Comment: I used the curl download instructions.  But I might have downloaded the wrong zip file...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AWS CLI have two versions available at the moment, `get-login-password` is only available in the **v2** of the SDK/CLI.

```sh
aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-west-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 123456789.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

---

Previous version **v1** uses the following command. `aws ecr get-login`

```sh
eval $(aws ecr get-login --registry-ids 123456789 --region eu-west-1 --no-include-email)
```

You can use `aws --version` to check what version of the CLI is installed at the moment.

```sh
aws --version
aws-cli/2.0.38 Python/3.7.4 Darwin/20.3.0 exe/x86_64
```

As per your question is this a "Mac-only" tool? No this is available for Windows, Mac and Linux as well as for x86 and ARM architecture.

I've just ran their installation command and it works for me.

```sh
root@Dummy:~# curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 35.8M  100 35.8M    0     0  8827k      0  0:00:04  0:00:04 --:--:-- 8827k
root@Dummy:~# unzip awscliv2.zip
Archive:  awscliv2.zip
   creating: aws/
   creating: aws/dist/
  inflating: aws/README.md
  inflating: aws/THIRD_PARTY_LICENSES
  inflating: aws/install
   creating: aws/dist/_struct/
   creating: aws/dist/awscli/
......
root@Dummy:~#
root@Dummy:~#
root@Dummy:~# aws --version
aws-cli/2.1.37 Python/3.8.8 Linux/5.4.34-1-pve exe/x86_64.ubuntu.20 prompt/off
root@Dummy:~#
```

Comment: Interesting, I thought I had installed v2.  Give me a minute

Comment: Yep, I had downloaded the latest V1 client.  Accepting this answer, thanks!

Comment: I still recommend that you upgrade to the **v2** as they've made some breaking changes to the APIs and some functions/commands might not work on _v1_. [Breaking changes – Migrating from AWS CLI version 1 to version 2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cliv2-migration.html)

Comment: Sorry to clarify, downloading v1 was the mistake.  It worked when I downloaded v2

Comment: This issue will become more pertinent as we are compelled to update our AWS CodeBuild docker images to ones that only support the v2 subcommand.  I was prompted by such an AWS email today and upgrading from aws/codebuild/standard:3.0 to 5.0 broke my build.  Updating the ecr login as described here restored the success.